# django edit queryset objects without affecting database

Tags: python, django

I have not found good enough answer yet so I am asking here. I have models for dividend and stock.

```
class Dividend(models.Model):
    attributes...
    stock = models.ForeignKey(Stock)
```

I need to create a copy of Queryset because I want to pass dividends with some extra values to my template and I do not want these extra values to be inserted to database.

```
dividend_set = stock.dividend_set.all().order_by('date')
dividend_set.create(...)
```

How can I do this? Above code will create data in my stock.dividend_set. Do I have to use deepcopy or convert queryset to list? Or is there more elegant way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One simple method is to convert the queryset to a list.  The list will contain instances of your model.  You can do whatever you like with those instances and nothing will be saved to the database unless you call `save` or one of the other methods that writes to the database.

```
dividend_set = stock.dividend_set.all().order_by('date')
dividends = list(dividend_set)
for dividend in dividends:
    dividend.extra_value1 = 'foo'
    dividend.extra_value2 = 'bar'
# now pass the dividends list to your template as part of your context rather than the qs
```

Comment: I've read about list. But djangoproject.com says it could have `large memory overhead`. I don't have many dividends, so I may use it. But I thought there would be more elegant way working with objects without saving it. Thanks for answer!

Comment: Well, your objects have to make it into memory at some point if you want to change them.  They probably are already getting pulled into memory while rendering your template.  If your template includes a `for` loop over the queryset, just for instance, Django will pull the whole queryset into memory in exactly the same way as the `list` constructor.